# Can't get Ruby to update properly

Tags: linux, arch-linux, ruby

(Using Archlinux) I downloaded Ruby 1.8.7-174 a while ago and installed it via the tarball (not pacman). I was trying to update to 1.8.7-299, but I can't get it to work. Per the readme, I do the following steps, all of which complete without error:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

After install finishes however, I still have -174 installed instead of -299. I'm confused! Can anyone tell me what's happening here? I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the make install as root ? Otherwise it will install in the current folder and not be in your $PATH